# LinkedList index off by one

Tags: java

So, I have this function listOrder() that checks to make sure my LinkedList is in the expected order. But every single time I run it, I'm off by one index. So, it'll expect the value at index 0, but then it gets the item at index 1, and then it loops to expect the value at index 1, but then it gets the item at index 2. I'm pretty lost on what the issue could be here. I think the problem has to do with my iterator class.

```
class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
private ListNode<T> current;

public ListIterator(ListNode<T> node) {
    current = node;
}

//Move to the next position
public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (current==null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        current = current.next;
    }
    return current.payload;
}

//Makes sure there is another spot to move to.
public boolean hasNext() {
    boolean freeSpace;

    if (current.next == null) {
        freeSpace = false;
    } else {
        freeSpace = true;
    }

    return freeSpace;
}
```

}

Comment: Since your expected numbers are also being generated randomly, statistically speaking, you should _never_ see an expected value.  The error message you are seeing is misleading, because it broadcasts the wrong problem.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `ListIterator`?

Comment: @user7 Added as requested

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `next` method, You are not returning the data (`payload`) on the `front` node. I would suggest to change it as

```
public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
    T data;
    if (current == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        data = current.payload
        current = current.next;
    }
    return data;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return current != null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are generating `ll` and `expected` number randomly.

```
Random rnd = new Random(0);
rnd.nextInt();
```

Hence you cannot compare `ll` and `expected`.

Comment: Note, the seed of `Random` is reset to `0`.